# d3js prevent forceSimulation from recalculating position all the time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to build a force layout that will allow me to visualize the flow of objects in a system.
I want to show how many objects are on a specific state and when a state change I want to update my graph.

I've [built a prototype](https://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/hqx201L9/), but I've noticed that D3.js is recalculating transform of each node even when they don't need to move:

[image]

can this be fixed? maybe there is an option to add minimum value for an update?

I've declared force layout this way:

```
const force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id((d) => d.id).distance(150))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
  .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
  .on('tick', tick);
```

After changing `alphaTarget` to `alpha` recalculation stopped, but I got another bug:
I've added drag functionality and it stopped working with above changes.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/hqx201L9/84/) is the version with fixed recalculation but with drag problem.

Answer (score 4):

The culprit is in your `restart()` function:

```
force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
```

The way you are reheating your simulation by setting `.alphaTarget(0.3)` is not correct. `alphaTarget` is a configuration parameter which controls the way `alpha` decreases. Figuratively speaking, `alpha`—for as long as it is greater than `alphaMin`— is headed towards `alphaTarget`. The heat in the system is measured by `alpha` which can be thought of as dynamic data; `alphaTarget`, on the other hand, resembles more or less static data.

Furthermore, it is important to have `alphaTarget` set to a value less than `alphaMin` or else your simulation is going to run indefinitely because `alpha`, while on its way towards `alphaTarget` so to speak, is never going to be less than `alphaMin`.

Thus, if you want to reheat your system, you have to manipulate `alpha` instead of `alphaTarget`. Changing above mentioned line to the following is all it takes to get the desired effect.

```
force.alpha(0.3).restart();
```

Have a look at the following snippet, which is basically a fork of your JSFiddle, to see it in action.

```js
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click", function() {
  AddNewLink(null, 1);
});
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function() {
  AddNewLink(1, 2);
});
document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("click", function() {
  AddNewLink(2, 3);
});
document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("click", function() {
  AddNewLink(1, 3);
});
document.getElementById("e").addEventListener("click", function() {
  AddNewLink(3, 4);
});
document.getElementById("f").addEventListener("click", function() {
  AddNewLink(4, 5);
});

function AddNewLink(from, to) {
  var startNode;
  var start = availableNodes.find(x => x.id === from);
  if (start !== undefined) {
    //check if this node is already added
    var foundStart = nodes.find(x => x.id == start.id);
    if (foundStart === undefined) {
      nodes.push(start);
      startNode = start;
    } else {
      foundStart.value--;
      if (foundStart.value < 0) foundStart.value = 0;
      startNode = foundStart;
    }
  }

  var endNode;
  var end = availableNodes.find(x => x.id === to);
  if (end !== undefined) {
    //check if this node is already added
    var foundEnd = nodes.find(x => x.id == end.id);
    if (foundEnd === undefined) {
      nodes.push(end);
      endNode = end;
      end.value++;
    } else {
      foundEnd.value++;
      endNode = foundEnd;
    }
  }
  //console.log(startNode, endNode);

  if (startNode !== undefined && endNode !== undefined) {
    links.push({
      source: startNode,
      target: endNode
    });
  }

  restart();
}



// set up SVG for D3
const width = 400;
const height = 400;
const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .on('contextmenu', () => {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
  })
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

var availableNodes = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Start",
  value: 0,
  reflexive: false
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Node 1",
  value: 0,
  reflexive: false
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Node 2",
  value: 0,
  reflexive: false
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "Node 3",
  value: 0,
  reflexive: false
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: "Finish",
  value: 0,
  reflexive: false
}];

// set up initial nodes and links
//  - nodes are known by 'id', not by index in array.
//  - reflexive edges are indicated on the node (as a bold black circle).
//  - links are always source < target; edge directions are set by 'left' and 'right'.
let nodes = [
  availableNodes[0], availableNodes[1], availableNodes[2]
];
let links = [{
    source: nodes[0],
    target: nodes[1]
  },
  {
    source: nodes[1],
    target: nodes[2]
  }
];

// init D3 force layout
const force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id((d) => d.id).distance(150))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
  .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
  .on('tick', tick);

// define arrow markers for graph links
svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
  .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
  .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
  .attr('refX', 8)
  .attr('markerWidth', 3)
  .attr('markerHeight', 3)
  .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .append('svg:path')
  .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
  .attr('fill', '#000');


// handles to link and node element groups
let path = svg.append('svg:g').attr('id', 'lines').selectAll('path');
let circle = svg.append('svg:g').attr('id', 'circles').selectAll('g');

// update force layout (called automatically each iteration)
function tick() {
  // draw directed edges with proper padding from node centers
  path.attr('d', (d) => {
    const deltaX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    const deltaY = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    const dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    const normX = deltaX / dist;
    const normY = deltaY / dist;
    const sourcePadding = d.left ? 17 : 12;
    const targetPadding = d.right ? 17 : 12;
    const sourceX = d.source.x + (sourcePadding * normX);
    const sourceY = d.source.y + (sourcePadding * normY);
    const targetX = d.target.x - (targetPadding * normX);
    const targetY = d.target.y - (targetPadding * normY);

    return `M${sourceX},${sourceY}L${targetX},${targetY}`;
  });

  circle.attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
}

// update graph (called when needed)
function restart() {
  // path (link) group
  path = path.data(links);

  // remove old links
  path.exit().remove();

  // add new links
  path = path.enter().append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
    .merge(path);

  // circle (node) group
  // NB: the function arg is crucial here! nodes are known by id, not by index!
  circle = circle.data(nodes, (d) => d.id);

  // update existing nodes (reflexive & selected visual states)
  circle.selectAll('circle')
    .style('fill', (d) => colors(d.id))
    .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive);

  circle.selectAll('text.value').text((d) => d.value);

  // remove old nodes
  circle.exit().remove();

  // add new nodes
  const g = circle.enter().append('svg:g');

  g.append('svg:circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', 12)
    .style('fill', (d) => colors(d.id))
    .style('stroke', (d) => d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).darker().toString())
    .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive)

  // show node IDs
  g.append('svg:text')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 4)
    .attr('class', 'value')
    .text((d) => d.value);

  g.append('svg:text')
    .attr('x', 20)
    .attr('y', 4)
    .attr('class', 'name')
    .text((d) => d.name);

  circle = g.merge(circle);

  // set the graph in motion
  force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .force('link').links(links);

  force.alpha(0.3).restart();
}

restart();
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: #FFF;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  cursor: default;
}

path.link.selected {
  stroke-dasharray: 10, 2;
}

path.link.dragline {
  pointer-events: none;
}

path.link.hidden {
  stroke-width: 0;
}

circle.node.reflexive {
  stroke: #000 !important;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}

text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

text.value {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.1/d3.js"></script>
<button id='a'>1</button>
<button id='b'>1>2</button>
<button id='c'>2>3</button>
<button id='d'>1>3</button>
<button id='e'>3>4</button>
<button id='f'>4>5</button>
<svg width="400" height="400"></svg>
```

Comment: thanks for quickly fixing my code. I've based my prototype on one of many examples and they all use alphaTarget, now this looks much better :)

Comment: changing `alphaTarget` to `alpha` solved one problem but it introduced another one. Please take a look at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/achk0u73/ here I've added basic node movement. if I change the code according to Your answer after some time I'm unable to move nodes. This is probably because at the start the nodes are moving and when they move to target position everything stops, including drag functionality. can this also be solved?

Comment: @Misiu You need to keep the simulation running while dragging. Putting a `force.alpha(0.3).restart();` in the `dragged()` handler function does the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/hmuw7roq/. This did previously work because your simulation was still running in the background. Note, that this is just an aftereffect of solving the real issue in your question. I hesitate editing this into my answer as it has got nothing to do with your main problem. This might be worth a follow-up question, though.

Comment: that works just fine :) I'll edit my question and Your answer with proper solution. Thanks for help!

Comment: my edits got rejected, could You please edit Your answer and include code snippet for the second solution?

Comment: @Misiu It was rejected for a reason. As I mentioned in a previous [comment](/q/55730704/55850573#comment98376242_55850573) this answer fully addresses and solves your main problem. That this breaks the drag behavior is a follow-up issue worth a different question. Previous versions of your question didn't mention any drag at all; you broadened the scope by editing in new information after the first solution was available. This is usually frowned upon by the community and I'd like to stick to the convention to keep it to one issue per post.